# a positive interger solution for a fraction of logarithm

Tags: number-theory, functions

Let $r_1,r_2,n$ be positive integers with $r_1<n,r_2<n$ and $r_1\neq r_2$. Given
$$
n=\frac{r_1\ln(r_1+1)-r_2\ln(r_2+1)}{\ln(r_1+1)-\ln(r_2+1)}.
$$
My question is: Can you find $r_1,r_2$ and $n$ which satisfy the above equation ? 
(keep in your mind: $n$ must be a positive integer).

Answer (score 1):

$r_1=7$, $r_2=3$, since it results

$$
\frac{7*3\ln(2)-3*2\ln(2)}{3\ln(2)-2\ln(2)}=15.
$$